# AjaxcontrolToolkit does not work after deploy to the Windows Server

Tags: webforms, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, windows-server-2012

I had a problems of AjaxcontrolToolkit does not work after deploy to the Windows Server.
The application with AjaxControlToolkit, its work at my machine, after deploy to Server , its diid not work.
Here with my source code (Default.apsx)

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
<cc1:ComboBox ID="ComboBox1" runat="server" DropDownStyle="DropDownList" AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceEng" DataTextField="R1" DataValueField="EngagementCode" MaxLength="0" AutoPostBack="True" class="WindowsStyle" Width="400px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged" AppendDataBoundItems="True" >
                         <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                     </cc1:ComboBox>
```

Inside the Web.config

```
 <controls>

        <add tagPrefix="cc1" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />

      </controls>
```

Here with the result before deploy to the Windows Server 2012.
[image]

Here with the result after deploy to the Windows Server 2012.
[image]

Anyone facing the same issue?

Comment: Did you deploy the AjaxControlToolkit.dll, too? Also, post error message if any.

Comment: @dpant When Generate the Publish file, the bin folder already included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use EnableCdn in ScriptManager

```
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" EnableCdn="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

and

the  section

```
 <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.5.2/1/WebForms.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.5.2/1/MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.5.2/1/MicrosoftAjax.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.5.2/1/MicrosoftAjaxTimer.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
```

References:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/ajax/cdn/overview#ajaxmicrosoftcom_renamed_to_ajaxaspnetcdncom_18